# Issue of not filtering by Id on Task

Tags: apex, search, id

I'm performing Search for OwnerId on Task object . I have a User (i.e. Owner) named "Nisarg" . Hence when I search for "Nisarg" it does not give me anything.

When I Debug this in the Console , the following is what I get. What it does is , it searches for the SObject and Status, but the requirement is also to search for the OwnerId as well on Task which is not happening .. Please help me correct the mistake(s).

```
USER_DEBUG [131]|DEBUG|Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task  where (Subject like '%Nisarg%' OR Status like '%Nisarg%')  Order By Subject limit 3 offset 0

 private static string JoinSetIds(Set<Id> objIds)
 {
   if(objIds == null || objIds.size() == 0)
   {
     return '';
   }
   List<string> lIds = new List<string>();
   for(Id pId : objIds)
   {
     lIds.add((string)pId);
   }
   return '(\'' + String.join(lIds, '\',\'' ) + '\')';
} 

public void queryTasks(){

    String qStr2= searchText;
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    String strnormal = '';
    try{
         mydate = date.parse(qStr2);
    }catch(Exception e)
    { }

    String strDate = '';
    String ownerIdsCondition = '';
    if(tasks!=null&&tasks.size()>0)
    {
      for(Task t : tasks)
      {
        if(!ownerIds.contains(t.OwnerId))
          ownerIds.add(t.OwnerId);
      }
      ownerIdsCondition = ' OwnerId IN '+JoinSetIds(ownerIds) + ' and ';
    }
    if(mydate != null) {
     // strnormal = String.valueOf(mydate );
      String[] qstr3 = String.valueOf(mydate).split(' ',2); 
      strDate = ownerIdsCondition+' ActivityDate =  '+ qstr3[0] + ' ';
    }else{

       strDate  =  ownerIdsCondition+'(Subject like \'%'+searchText +'%\' OR Status like \'%' +searchText+ '%\') ' + ' Order By '  + sortField;
    }

    String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,ActivityDate from Task where '+strDate+' limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;  
     System.debug(qStr); 
     tasks = Database.query(qStr);         

 } 

    <apex:column headerValue="OwnerId">
        <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.OwnerId}"/>
    </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't follow the logic of the code you have posted but offer the code below as an example of how to build dynamic SOQL for several search terms OR'd together. It may or may not fit your specific requirements.

The code makes use of dynamic SOQL's ability to bind simple variables into the query which e.g. avoids the need to build strings of comma separated quoted values and avoids the risk of [SOQL injection](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).

The user name search part makes use of a [relationship query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) feature that allows the "where" clause to reference fields in related objects.

```
public String subjectSearch {get; set;}
public String statusSearch {get; set;}
public String userSearch {get; set;}

public Task[] tasks {get; set;}

public void queryTasks() {

    // These simple variables can be bound into the dynamic SOQL
    String subjectLike = likeTerm(subjectSearch);
    String statusLike = likeTerm(statusSearch);
    String userLike = likeTerm(userSearch);

    String[] terms = new String[] {};
    if (subjectLike != null) {
        terms.add('Subject like :subjectLike');
    }
    if (statusLike != null) {
        terms.add('Status like :statusLike');
    }
    if (userLike != null) {
        terms.add('Owner.Name like :userLike');
    }

    String soql = 'Select OwnerId, Subject, Status, ActivityDate from Task';
    if (terms.size() > 0) {
        soql += ' where ' + String.join(terms, ' or ');
    }

    // Append further terms here e.g. order by, limit, offset

    tasks = Database.query(soql);
}

private Boolean likeTerm(String s) {
    return s != null && s.length() > 0 ? '%' + s + '%' : null;
}
```